# Convert pct change on minute data for multiple days

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a dataframe that contains stock prices at the minute frequency for multiple days and I would like to use pct_change() to compute the returns from one minute to the next but I would like to skip the last observation each day so I don't compute the pct change from the close of the day to the next day's open but rather leave that one NaN. I was thinking to do this with groupby but couldn't quite figure it out:

So this is what I would like:

```
enter code here

data     price    pct_change
1/1/2020 9:30 1.1 
1/1/2020 9:31 1.2 pct_change from 1.1 to 1.2
1/1/2020 9:32 1.1 pct_change from 1.2 to 1.1
...
 1/1/2020 16:00 1.8 pct_change from ... to 1.8
1/2/2020 9:30  1.3 NaN
1/2/2020 9:31  1.2 pct_change from 1.3 to 1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I could just compute pct_change and the use loc to set all rows with 9:30 equal to NaN.